# orangehrm 3.3.3 installation error on Windows & Using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost, orangehrm

I've been trying to instal OrangeHRM 3.3.3 just so I could test it out using XAMPP on my Windows & machine but I'm stuck on a certain page. Here are the issues I've encountered:

1. I Had to dive into the code and update all  PHP functions from "mysql" to "mysqli"
2. I have installed Apache and MySQL as services on my PC.
3. I have edited 
   $this->dbuser = ''; root 
   $this->dbpass = ''; MyRootUserPassword "************"

Yet I still can't get past Database Configuration.
Please see Screenshot Inset. Someone Please give me pointers on what to do?

Cheers.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnQw7.png)

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH2dy.png)

Comment: Directly editing the mysql to mysqli might not fix your problem. Which version of PHP are you having? Is mysql running on the specified port? The information provided by you is not enough

Comment: I'm using PHP version: 7.1.4. And yes MySQL is running on the same port specified. What other information would you require to help me out so I provide it right away. Also see second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that OrangeHrm 3.3.3 doesn't work with PHP 7, it only works with PHP 5 and below. After installing Xampp with PHP version 5, I was able to install Orangehrm with no issues. I expect the next update to include PHP 7 support.